# XML schema for XML reports on SQL Server reporting services

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

This may be a newbie question, and I have done quite a lot of searching for an answer but have had no luck.

I am using SSRS on SQL Server 2008 R2 (Standard edition) to generate XML reports. I have developed my report in Report builder 3 and uploaded the report to the Report server.

So far so good

Now I want to have a subscription that generates the reports in XML format and deposits it into a folder

No problem with this straight forward enough

How do I install an XML transform or specify the actual XML schema for the rendered document as I don't want to manually handle the generated report.

In the Report Builder software there appears to be a report property where I can specify as path which would have to be to a file on my local desktop but nothing on how to supply a similar file to the reporting server to use.

How do I do this?

And I thank all of you kindly stackoverflow souls in advance for your collective wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is Read the Manual !
However finding information through the myriad of MS pages is an excercise in Google-foo 
and old fashioned primary school collage.

You upload XSL through the Report Manager UI using IE and make sure that you have a server side path specified in the DataTransform field in Report Properties in ReportBuilder 3 for your RDL file

The essential confusion that I suffered from was that I thought the XSL transform would be incorporated into the RDL file for publication to the report server. It isn't

SO 
For the DataTransform property:
1 A local absolute file path with a drive letter will not work
2 Use a path that makes sense on the report server 
3 Either a relative path to the XSL file from the location of the RDL file
OR an absolute path from the Report Server should be used

Angus